# Group and gave ranks based on certain conditions

Tags: sql, datetime

I want to give rank to below data based on time (if the timestamp difference is less the 15 mins then same rank else rank +1 )
E.g

- time : 06:10:32 and 06:12:38 should get rank 1
- time : 13:36:44 and 13:40:41 and 13:44:47 should get rank 2
- and last 4 rows should get rank 3

```
user_id ride_id      createdat_local    
2681233 96783742    2017-10-04 06:10:32 
2681233 96784171    2017-10-04 06:12:38 
2681233 96924751    2017-10-04 13:36:44 
2681233 96925561    2017-10-04 13:40:41 
2681233 96926560    2017-10-04 13:44:47 
2681233 96994651    2017-10-04 18:12:29 
2681233 96995953    2017-10-04 18:18:16 
2681233 96996937    2017-10-04 18:22:15 
2681233 96997195    2017-10-04 18:24:00
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Is it sql-server or postgresql?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database types.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: its redshift(psql)

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2012+:

Using the window function `lag()` in a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to get the `datediff()` compared to the previous row value for `createdat_local`, and then `sum() over()` with conditional aggregation to generate the rank:

```
;with cte as (
select *
  , datediff(minute,lag(createdat_local) over (
      partition by user_id
      order by createdat_local
      ),createdat_local) as prev_dat
from t
)
select user_id, ride_id, createdat_local
  , sum(case when coalesce(prev_dat,16)>15 then 1 else 0 end) over (
    partition by user_id
    order by createdat_local
    ) as rank
from cte
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/EQUC48356

returns:

```
+---------+----------+---------------------+------+
| user_id | ride_id  |   createdat_local   | rank |
+---------+----------+---------------------+------+
| 2681233 | 96783742 | 2017-10-04 06:10:32 |    1 |
| 2681233 | 96784171 | 2017-10-04 06:12:38 |    1 |
| 2681233 | 96924751 | 2017-10-04 13:36:44 |    2 |
| 2681233 | 96925561 | 2017-10-04 13:40:41 |    2 |
| 2681233 | 96926560 | 2017-10-04 13:44:47 |    2 |
| 2681233 | 96994651 | 2017-10-04 18:12:29 |    3 |
| 2681233 | 96995953 | 2017-10-04 18:18:16 |    3 |
| 2681233 | 96996937 | 2017-10-04 18:22:15 |    3 |
| 2681233 | 96997195 | 2017-10-04 18:24:00 |    3 |
+---------+----------+---------------------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks SqlZim, with your logic, I am able to achieve the same result in redshift

Answer (score 0):

Able to achieve the required result in redshift(psql)

Query:
with cte as (
select *, 
(DATEPART('hour',createdat_local) * 60 + DATEPART('minute',createdat_local)) - 
lag(DATEPART('hour',createdat_local) * 60 + DATEPART('minute',createdat_local) 
) over(partition by user_id order by createdat_local)  as diff_in_minutes
from t 
)
select user_id, ride_id, createdat_local
  , sum(case when coalesce(diff_in_minutes,16)>15 then 1 else 0 end) over (
    partition by user_id
    order by createdat_local rows between unbounded preceding and current row
    ) as rank
from cte;